How to get a json formatted file from imported object in es6?
If I have file places.mjs
export default { STATES: { 'AU' : {...}, 'US' : {...} } };

What is the javascript way to get the json into a file? I just need to remove the "export detault", and the trailing semicolon and this can be read with
let json = require('json5')
let fs = require('fs-extra')
let a = json.parse(fs.readFileSync("./places.mjs"))

I can do this with sed, but what is the jacascript way to do this? I want to read an mjs and write json.
-- Removing the unwanted text and trailing semicoln 
sed -i '' -e 's/export default//g' places.mjs 
sed -i '' -r 's/(.*);/\1/' places.mjs
---- run this program and print output to out.json 
let json = require('json5') 
let fs = require('fs-extra') 
let a = json.parse(fs.readFileSync("./places.mjs" 
console.log(a)
node chris.cjs > out.json 
-- Adding the export default back, and trailing semicolon 
echo "$(echo -n 'export default '; cat out.json)" > out.json 
echo ';' >> out.json

Works as expected, but how to just handle it in javascript

places.mjs is not JSON. You can't parse it.
